# Multiple definitions for the same name in Flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm a Flex newbie and was wondering if it is possible to have multiple definitions for the same name in Flex. Such as:

```
/* DEFINITIONS */
FRUITS "APPLE" | "ORANGE" | "LEMON"
```

Also, what can we do and not do with string constants in flex's regular expressions? Can we  use symbols such as $ and *? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The right side of a definition is an ordinary regular expression, so you could write

```
FRUIT APPLE|ORANGE|LEMON
```

or perhaps

```
FRUIT (PINE)?APPLE|GRAPE(FRUIT)?|ORANGE|LEMON
```

and refer to it later in the rules section with

```
{FRUIT}
```

but I doubt that you would really want to.  It's a crude way to recognize keyword tokens.

It's best to use definitions (think of them as macros) like these examples:

```
LETTER [a-zA-Z]
DIGIT [0-9]
ALPHANUMERIC [a-zA-Z0-9]
```